# Am I the only one experiencing problems with R's haven package?

Tags: r, stata, r-haven

I want to open a stata file in R, via `haven::read_dta()`. I'have created my script a few weeks ago and it all worked well until now: suddenly, when I try loading the data my session crashes ("R Session Aborted"). A colleague of mine is having the same problem.

I' ve tried many things: choosing the correct working directory via `setwd()`, choosing the file via `choose.files()`, entering the filepath with "/", "//" and "\" but nothing seems to work.

They way it worked until now was:

```
install.packages("haven")
library(haven)

my_data <- read_dta("my_path_structure\\file_name.dta")
```

Anyone having the same problem?

**EDIT:** Problem should be fixed soon. For more information see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/pull/619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

On the 14th, Haven updated to [2.4.0](https://haven.tidyverse.org/news/index.html) where they internally upgraded to [ReadStat 1.1.5.](https://github.com/WizardMac/ReadStat/releases) which handles the import of `.dta` files. There doesn't appear to be any codebreaking updates in ReadStat 1.1.5..

I was able to reproduce your abort error in R Studio which gives no information. I went directly to the R Console and it gives me the following segmentation error after running the same code:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x0, cause 'invalid permissions'
```

Given that this was not an issue with the previous build of Haven, I would make a bug report with the developer.

### Temporary Solution

I was able to get around this issue by using the [readstata13](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readstata13/readstata13.pdf) package instead. Here is an example,

```
install.packages("readstata13")
library(readstata13)
my_data <- read.dta13("my_path_structure/file_name.dta")
```

Comment: forward-slash `/` should work as a path separator in R on any OS ... (`\\` *only* works on Windows)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, I've gone ahead and edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @JesseKaczmarski. May I ask you how you've produced this feedback from the console? Because if I enter the code directly there the window shuts down immediately.

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry I wasn't more specific. Instead of using the R console in the R studio IDE, I used the R Console that gets installed when you first install R. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @Jesse Kaczmarski that's interesting because I used that console too but I do not receive any meaningfull feedback. Hm, anyway, I have already reported the bug.

Comment: @micsky Oh wow that sure is interesting. [Here is a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/pPL9q0K) of the output if you want to use it for the bug report.

Comment: @JesseKaczmarski I have already used your code snippet and posted the link of this whole thread in my report but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @micsky wonderful! Hopefully this gets resolved soon because I really like Haven.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same issue. My solution was to install Haven 2.3.1.

```
packageUrl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/haven/haven_2.3.1.tar.gz"

# only needed if haven is attached
detach("package:haven", unload = TRUE)

install.packages(packageUrl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: True, that's one possibility to bypass the problem. But I guess this should not be the "final solution".

Answer (score 0):

As of 7/27/2021, this problem is fixed in the development version of Haven. Run `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/haven")`.